# Python/Pandas- applying label at trend shift (identifying local maxima and minima in dataset)

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv

So I have a CSV where I have stock prices and for every day (row) I have a corresponding column that shows whether the price increased or decreased over the previous day.

Task:I want to identify peaks and troughs (see example screenshot).
Logic: The last 'increase" cell before the trend changes should be labeled "peak".
Similarly for decrease...

[image]
I'm guessing this is going to use a loop with break/continue. 
I'll appreciate the exact recommendation for writing the code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a vectorised solution using `pandas` and `numpy` functionality.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'seq': ['inc', 'dec', 'inc', 'inc', 'inc', 'dec', 'dec', 'dec', 'inc']})

df['mark'] = df['seq'].map({'inc': 1, 'dec': -1}).diff().shift(-1).map(np.sign).fillna(0)
df['mark'] = df['mark'].map({-1: 'peak', 1: 'trough', 0: ''})

#    seq    mark
# 0  inc    peak
# 1  dec  trough
# 2  inc        
# 3  inc        
# 4  inc    peak
# 5  dec        
# 6  dec        
# 7  dec  trough
# 8  inc
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most `pythonic/efficient` way but this will work:

```
price = ['increase', 'increase', 'increase', 'decrease', 'decrease', 'increase']

break_point = []
for index, value in enumerate(price):
    try:
        if value == price[index + 1]:
            break_point.append(' ')
        else:
            if value == 'increase':
                break_point.append('peak')
            else:
                break_point.append('trough')
    except IndexError:
        break

print(break_point)
```